# Suppress darkening of main view when UIActionSheet displays

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I have a UIActionSheet and when it displays it darkens the main view behind it, I am under the impression this is default behavior for an action sheet.  My question is, how do I override this behavior to leave the main screen the same tint as it normally is?  I'm assuming I do something like:

```
mainView.alpha = 1f;
```

Or something...I can't remember if alpha needs to be maxed or 0 to leave a screen with the same coloration/transparency.  Anyways, if that is correct where should it happen?  My action sheet is being called in place of a keyboard for a UITextField.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change this behavior. `UIActionSheet` is actually presenting a whole new view overtop of your view. It's this additional view that adds the tint. There is no API to change this.

Your best solution is to implement your own custom equivalent to `UIActionSheet` so it does exactly what you want.